# What does the ' symbol mean in this context?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, asymptotics

This pertains to an explanation of Big-*O* notation:

> If one pair of witnesses is found, then there are infinitely many
>   pairs.  We can always make the k or the C larger and still maintain
>   the inequality *f*(x) <= *Cg*(x)
>
> Any pair C' and k' where C < k' and k < k' is also a pair of witnesses
>   since                                  whenever x > k̍ > k.

What does that apostrophe character about the Cs and Ks mean exactly?

Comment: It means they're completely different entities, different variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means other constants (than $C$ and $k$, respectively), but playing the same role. You can replace $C^\prime$ by $D$ and $k^\prime$ by $\ell$ if you prefer.